# Library transpilation using Babel (and Webpack) does not work when using required

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm trying to transpile the `marked` library during bundling to make it work on old Safari. My `webpack.config.js` (which includes Babel settings) looks like this:

```js
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        libraryTarget: "window",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                    },
                },
                exclude: {
                    and: [/node_modules/],
                    not: [/marked/],
                },
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

In my src files, if I do the following:

```
import { marked } from "marked";

// Use marked here
```

Then the transpilation works properly and it runs on my old Safari. However, if I do the following:

```
var marked = require("marked");

// Use marked here
```

Then the transpilation does not apply to `marked`, and my site breaks on Safari. So what gives? Am I missing something obvious?

My `pacakge.json` looks like this (no `type` property):

```
{
    ...
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.24.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.0",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
        "webpack": "^5.90.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
        ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "marked": "^12.0.1",
        ...
    },
}
```